# Does Uniswap Router02's getAmountsOut function consider pool fees when calculating a quote?

Tags: ethereum, uniswap

I'm wondering if the getAmountsOut function on Uniswap V2 Router02 contract takes into consideration the pool fees for the tokens when calculating the amount out or would I have to calculate this myself? The docs are quite vague in this regard https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/library#getamountsout

Uniswap V3 quoteExactInputSingle takes the pool fee as a parameter, so I assume that this is used in the calculation? https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/periphery/lens/Quoter#quoteexactinputsingle

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check how the fees are calculated in Uniswap v2 source code.

Here is [the matching example from SushiSwap repository](https://github.com/sushiswap/sushiswap/blob/master/protocols/sushiswap/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol#L193). You can see where 3/1000 (0.30%) gets calculated. The input amounts and output amounts must be such numbers that they satisfy Uniswap v2 fee conditions.

```
    // this low-level function should be called from a contract which performs important safety checks
    function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external lock {
        require(amount0Out > 0 || amount1Out > 0, 'UniswapV2: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT');
        (uint112 _reserve0, uint112 _reserve1,) = getReserves(); // gas savings
        require(amount0Out < _reserve0 && amount1Out < _reserve1, 'UniswapV2: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');

        uint balance0;
        uint balance1;
        { // scope for _token{0,1}, avoids stack too deep errors
        address _token0 = token0;
        address _token1 = token1;
        require(to != _token0 && to != _token1, 'UniswapV2: INVALID_TO');
        if (amount0Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token0, to, amount0Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
        if (amount1Out > 0) _safeTransfer(_token1, to, amount1Out); // optimistically transfer tokens
        if (data.length > 0) IUniswapV2Callee(to).uniswapV2Call(msg.sender, amount0Out, amount1Out, data);
        balance0 = IERC20Uniswap(_token0).balanceOf(address(this));
        balance1 = IERC20Uniswap(_token1).balanceOf(address(this));
        }
        uint amount0In = balance0 > _reserve0 - amount0Out ? balance0 - (_reserve0 - amount0Out) : 0;
        uint amount1In = balance1 > _reserve1 - amount1Out ? balance1 - (_reserve1 - amount1Out) : 0;
        require(amount0In > 0 || amount1In > 0, 'UniswapV2: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT');
        { // scope for reserve{0,1}Adjusted, avoids stack too deep errors
        uint balance0Adjusted = balance0.mul(1000).sub(amount0In.mul(3));
        uint balance1Adjusted = balance1.mul(1000).sub(amount1In.mul(3));
        require(balance0Adjusted.mul(balance1Adjusted) >= uint(_reserve0).mul(_reserve1).mul(1000**2), 'UniswapV2: K');
        }

        _update(balance0, balance1, _reserve0, _reserve1);
        emit Swap(msg.sender, amount0In, amount1In, amount0Out, amount1Out, to);
    }
```

Comment: Much appreciated. After actually delving into the contracts source code I finally understand.